How to Maintain Session in Next.js API Routes for SSO custom Integration with Auth0?
I’m working on a web application with two primary authentication methods:

Single Page Application (SPA) for user login with email/password.
Machine-to-Machine (M2M) app for backend processes.

Additionally, I’ve integrated a custom SSO with an external Identity Provider (IDP), SolidEarth, allowing users authenticated through SolidEarth to access my app. This integration works well within my Next.js API routes, where I’m able to retrieve user data.
The Issue
The main challenge I’m facing is maintaining a session for SSO users. My goal is to create and sustain sessions through my M2M app, compatible with users logging in via Auth0’s Universal Login page (Classic). However, once the session is set up on the API route, it doesn’t persist on the client side, redirecting users to the Auth0 login page.
My Approach So Far
I’m trying the following steps to handle SSO sessions:

Request a client token via the /oauth/token endpoint.
Check if the user exists with the /api/v2/users-by-email API.

If the user doesn’t exist, create them with /api/v2/users.
If they do, update their details with /api/v2/users/${id}.


Generate an Auth0 client token with /oauth/token and try to establish a session with it.
Attempt to persist the session.

The session works within the API route, but once redirected to the client side, it doesn’t persist, and the Auth0 login page appears.
The Code
Here’s the core part of my login API route in Next.js:
export default async function login(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    // Fetch SolidEarth user data
    const result = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SSO_ENDPOINT}/oauth/userinfo`, {
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + req.query.token },
    });
    const { email, family_name, given_name } = result.data;

    // Check or create Auth0 user
    const clientToken = await getAuth0ClientToken();
    let userExist = await auth0userExist(clientToken, email);

    if (!userExist) {
      userExist = await createAuth0User(clientToken, email, v4(), {
        user_metadata: { name: `${given_name} ${family_name}` },
      });
    }

    const userToken = await getAuth0UserToken(email, password);

    // Create session with Auth0
    const session = await sessionCache.fromTokenSet(new TokenSet(userToken));
    await sessionCache.create(req, res, session);

    // Redirect user to the home page
    res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/" }).end();
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}

My Goal
To enable a seamless login experience for SSO users (without needing the paid Auth0 Enterprise SSO solution), I’m looking for a free solution that would allow:

Manual session creation compatible with Auth0’s Universal Login experience.
Persistence of the session across client-side redirects.

Is there a way to handle this session persistence manually? Any pointers or references to documentation would be very helpful!
